# Truncating POSIXct time in (base) R

Tags: r, datetime

I wish to truncate POSIXct timestamps to minutes. For example

2020-11-30 08:33:53 UTC --->  2020-11-30 08:33:00 UTC

I know there is probably some libraries like lubridate that can do this but I wish to do this in base R. I am aware there is a "trunc" function for POSIXct which produces the desired result, but for some reason this function is painfully slow and uses huge amounts of memory (I have about 30 million timestamps).

I am wondering whether I can simply do

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2020-11-30 08:33:53", tz = "UTC")
as.POSIXct(60 * (as.numeric(x) %/% 60), tz = "UTC", origin = "1970-01-01")
```

This is clearly very fast and efficient, and seems to work on various examples, but is this a correct calculation? I am worried there might be some issues with leap seconds or something.

Comment: Leap seconds won't be a problem:  as `?POSIXct` says, ""POSIXct" times used by R do not include leap seconds on any platform."    I can't think of anything else that would cause problems.

Comment: Though @stefan's suggestion seems safer, and is only a little slower on my system:  1.7 sec instead of 1.1 sec to do 30 million truncations.

Comment: @user2554330 thanks. As noted I am aware of trunc(x, "mins"). Not sure if it depends on platform/version but call to this function on 30 million records lasted for 5 mins and exceeded 64GB of RAM on my linux machine.

Comment: Sorry. I overread the part with `trunc`. IMHO your computation is correct. Just checked on a vector of random date times and got the same result with your approach and with `as.POSIXct(trunc(xx, "mins"), tz = "UTC")`. But as you already noted your approach is faster and less demanding in terms of memory.

Comment: that means that base R is not the right tool for the job.